# How to make the camera move more frequently?

Tags: swift, camera, sprite-kit

I have a `Player` which is a custom `SKShapeNode` class object.
I added a `camera` to follow the player, it is working but I want the camera to follow the player more frequently. now it is just checking if the camera still has player inside its view, if it doesn't it moves the camera.
I tried to check the height of the screen and move it when I get close to the top but it didn't work.
This is the code I have now (runs in `update()` function):

```
if (!cameraNode.contains(mPlayer)) {
    moveCamera()
}
```

this is moveCamera():

```
func moveCamera(){
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: mPlayer.position.y + 600, duration: 0.1)
    cameraNode.run(moveAction)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how your scene is set up, but this might work:

```
let idealDistance: CGFloat = 600.0
let allowedDelta: CGFloat = 150.0

let offset = cameraNode.position.y - (mPlayer.position.y + idealDistance)

if abs(offset) > allowedDelta {
    moveCamera()
}
```

You can experiment with the allowedDelta value to see what works nicely.